# Как сделать работающий интернет на виртуальной машине VirtualBox Android x86?

Tags: android, wifi, virtualbox, x86

На VirtualBox есть виртуальные машины с Android 4.0, 3.0. Образы x86 asus-laptop. Но Wi-Fi включить там нельзя, не помогает не NAT, не Сетевой мост, не одно из списка. На компьютере Windows 11, версия VirtualBox 7.0.6. Возможно ли исправить эту проблему? Не помогает даже тип адаптера "PCnet-FAST III (Am79C973)"[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: почему не 12 андроид?